# Delphi Word Equation automation

Tags: delphi, ms-word, equation

Can anyone show me an example of automating an equation? I need to obtain something like in the following [image]

How can I do that? Of course the values are dynamic
Or is there a better approach?
I have a word document generated from delphi code, containing text, tables and I need a formula to be entered for display. So I do not need the result (I know math :))

Thank you

Comment: Your first problem would be identifying and then converting the formula in the document into some sort of "executable" structure. That is going to be hard enough. Only once that is done can you start to work out the result.

Comment: What version of MS-Word?  I read that its handling of equations changed in 2010 version ...

Comment: If you are using a version of Word that stores its files in XML format (using a docx extension) then you can open up the file in WinZip or 7-Zip and see how it is stored. The OpenOffice schema is documented at http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/ss.html

Comment: Use the macro recorder when composing the formula in Word and see what the code in VBA is.

Comment: I do not want the result to be displayed. I need to display exactly the formula in the image. Forget the math, if you don't understand, please go inside MSWord, insert, Equation, then go to Layout to see the options. I obtain nothing when I record the macro

Comment: For some clues on programmatic creation of Equations in Word, see the VBA approaches at http://superuser.com/questions/668739/how-to-create-an-augmented-matrix-in-word-2007-equations-editor/668985#668985 .

Comment: @bibadia - it would be very helpful if I had some delphi-pascal code... I do not think that this VBA code translates too well in delphi

Answer (score 0):

So far, my solution is to create the ecuation in LaTeX format, like this:

```
Nrg1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{15} riRi }{\sum_{i=1}^{15} ri } = \frac{2(4x4)+5(3x3)+3(2x2)+5(1x1)}{2x4+5x3+3x2+5x1} = \frac{94}{34} = 2,76
```

then copy it to clipboard, then paste it to http://formulasheet.com/#r%7Ced , "Render" it, then click on "Save Word", return to the word document and paste where I need my equation to be shown.

It works even if it is not completely "automatic".

If any of you have a better way I am waiting for your input. I would love to have a solution that does not force the user to make "manual" stuff.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you can use ArtFormulas, unit that i use in my project to calculate sample formule 
you can find it at

http://artsoft.nm.ru/works.html#formula

Comment: I do not want to calculate the result of a formula. I want to display the formula in the Word document just like in the picture above (the picture is a screenshot of the word document portion that shows the part with the formula) That is what I need. Not the result

Comment: You should really provide code with some explanation, not links, in order to suffice as an answer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer